NetTopologySuite convert hex string to Geometry (C#)
I have a string stored in Sql server with DataType Geography:
"0xE61000000104040000005C8FC2F5280C54C0A01A2FDD24C639409CC420B0723050C00C022B8716294040643BDF4F8D8750C09EEFA7C64B7732405C8FC2F5280C54C0A01A2FDD24C6394001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003"

I need to convert it in NTS Geometry. Im using the code:
  var reader = new WKBReader();
  Geometry g = reader.Read(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(coor2));

but isn't work, im receiving the exception
System.ArgumentException: Geometry type not recognized. GeometryCode: 784
   at NetTopologySuite.IO.WKBReader.Read(BinaryReader reader)

Any idea how to convert the string to Geometry?

This is MS-SqlServer's binary representation of a geography. You will have to use NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes to parse that.
